# Writing a grammar in VoiceXML to match # terminated digits or *1 or *2

Tags: grammar, voice, ivr, dtmf, voicexml

I an writing a VoiceXML app and i am having a problem. The application listens for DTMF tones only.

The user enters a confirmation number followed by #. They can also enter *1 or *2 to speak to customer service, or resend the confirmation message.

I am having trouble creating a grammer that will work for this. I've been able to use the built-in type `digits?minlength=1` and `termchar=#` just fine for the confirmation code. I've also been able to create a grammar that essentially duplicates the built `digits` functionality.

I can't get the *1, or *2 function to work! They are special as they have no termination char.

Does anyone have any clue how to approach this? Loosing hair here....
Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this example from the SRGS [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-grammar/#AppE). The pin example accepts *9.

Note, while this is in the specification, I've found some IVR engines that don't fully implement the specification.  In particular, watch out for built-in assumptions for both # and *.  Termination reasons can also be a bit inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks. this is exactly what I am looking for. Just need to see if it works now....